QGIS to Web plugin retain symbology and legend functionality like the interactive hide and show legend interactive checkbox category functionality
When using QGIS Prizen on the desktop, I can use the Symbology feature to display a graduated or categorized legend for a layer called "General Business," which includes five variations of businesses like malls, single tenant complexes, data warehouses, and others. This allows me to click check marks to show only specific dots on the map, especially when using primary colors for differentiation. However, when I export the map using the QGIS2Web plugin, I lose this functionality.
Any solutions?
Some maps I have have more than 5 elements so after a while it would be difficult to hard code these into a JavaScript one by one.

You could create a layer group in QGIS and inside put your duplicate layer 5 times. Set the graded style in each one, but keeping only one substyle for each one.
Or if you don't want to touch the QGIS project you can use the filter in the Appearance tab that only works with Leaflet Export. You need to select only the affected field and export, in the webmap you can turn on your layer and then filter the data in the map according to the set field.
